# How to resolve missing Java EE Server Libraries in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, webserver

[image]

Can you suggest how to add server in the libraries section of netbeans for Java.

Comment: you need to add tomcat server to `Server` list not in library

Comment: Always consider accepting answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 9):

To resolve this issue, you need to add Server to `Netbeans -> Service` list.

You could also follow below steps :

**1. Identify the project, which has missing server libraries**

[image]

**2. Right click on project and click `Resolve Missing Server Problem..`**

[image]

**3. Then, Select the appropriate Server as per your project requirement, if not available in the list, then add the server.**

[image]

**Now, you can verify your project.**

[image]